# Validating custom member fields - expressionengine registration form

Tags: validation, field, expressionengine

I've setup an ExpressionEngine site with a custom member field. This field is showing up on the registration form but I need to validate it and can't find any documentation on how to do this.

The field is a company code and is used to assign the user to a company, so it basically needs to check against the company channel entries to make sure that the custom member field matches one of the entries code, is this possible?

Comment: Hey Nick, you may want to check out expressionengine.stackexchange.com for your EE-specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using jQuery validate to validate the form, I populated a json file with the correct entries and used validate to check the forms entry.